# How to encode multiple results from mysql in php...I am getting 5 results but when i run the API it doesn't show any data as JSON format

Tags: php, android, mysql

I made an API in php to search from mysql database and database is giving me 5 results but in my php API when i run it...it isn't showing any data as response below is my API code.

This is my API of Php i am taking packagename as input in header and then find that input in mysql database which should return me with 5 results and i have to encode these 5 results into json nd send it as response.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "package";

//Create Connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
//Check Connection
if($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection Failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$packagename = (print_r($_SERVER['HTTP_PACKAGENAME'],true));
//$pass = (print_r($_SERVER['HTTP_PASSWORD'],true));
//print_r($_SERVER);

//print_r(apache_request_headers());
$sql = "select * from  `package_details` where Package_Name='$packagename' ";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if($result->num_rows>0) {
    //$response["package_details"] = array();
    //Output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        //temp user array
        $user = array();

        $user["id"] = $row["id"];
        $user["Package_Name"] = $row["Package_Name"];
        $user["Package_Day"] = $row["Package_Day"];
        $user["Package_Description"] = $row["Package_Description"];

        //push single product into final response array
        //array_push($response["package_details"], $user);
    }
    //success
    //$response["success"] = "valid";
    //echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($user);
} else {
    //no products found
    $response["package_details"] = array();
    while($row = null) {

    $user = array();
        $user["id"] = $row[null];
        $user["Name"] = $row[null];
        $user["Contact_Number"] = $row[null];
        $user["Email_Id"] = $row[null];


        //push single product into final response array
        array_push($response["package_details"], $user);
    }
        $response["success"] = "invalid";
    //$response["success"] = "invalid";
    //$response["message"] = "No Products Found";

    //echo no users JSON
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Comment: You dont need to SHOUT, we can hear you

Comment: i am not shouting. i am typing

Comment: I have never heard of `$_SERVER['HTTP_PACKAGENAME']` is this something specific to your server?

Comment: No. when you send a parameter as header to a webservice then server stores all incoming headers in $_server array.

Comment: so i should declare it before the while loop?

Comment: i did it. but still it's showing me only last result. first four are not shown

Comment: `echo $packagename = (print_r($_SERVER['HTTP_PACKAGENAME'],true));` @AnandSingh what shows up when you echo that? `$_SERVER['HTTP_PACKAGENAME']` isn't part of the `$_SERVER` superglobal http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php nor did I find anything on Google about it. Use error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: and check for errors on the query with `mysqli_error($conn)` should there be any.

Answer (score 0):

You were only json encoding the last `$user` and not the array of users that you should be putting in `$response['package_details']`

See the amended code below

```
$response = array();

if($result->num_rows>0) {

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $user = array();

        $user["id"]                  = $row["id"];
        $user["Package_Name"]        = $row["Package_Name"];
        $user["Package_Day"]         = $row["Package_Day"];
        $user["Package_Description"] = $row["Package_Description"];

        //push single product into final response array
        $response["package_details"][] = $user;
    }
    //success
    $response["success"] = "valid";

} else {

    //no products found
    $response["success"] = "invalid";
    $response["message"] = "No Products Found";
}

echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: Okhay. But now it's showing nothing as response. not even the last result as before

Comment: yes I have checked it again. but still it doesn't give me any response

Comment: Hmmm thats very odd

Comment: $response["package_details"][] = $user...when i remove [] from this line then it shows last result...but with this [] it shows me nothing

Comment: Try initializing the $response array above the IF

Comment: This makes no sense, am I going mad?

Comment: How are you checking for the response?

Comment: well. Don't know about you but i will surely be mad if this doesn't work till night.

Comment: i am using rested extension in mozilla...and passing.....packagename as Name and Combo (Manali+Shimla) as value

Comment: The more I look at this, the more I think you are misinterpreting the output from this somehow

Comment: yes i also think that i am not correctly processing the output of query. Please help me out.

Comment: I have no idea how to help you with that

Comment: Edit your question and add the code that you are using to process the response

Comment: Well then show how you send the request to action this PHP script

Comment: I can't send you screenshot because i am new here and i have not yet gained enough reputation to post an image. but i am using RESTED client in mozilla to test my API by sending 1 parameter as header nd it is giving me output of 5 results because when i store that $result in a $data array using foreach loop and use print_r($data) then it's is printing 5 arrays as results but when i try to encode it in json. it won't give me any response